# Can't run project locally due to "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" in Learning AngularJS Chapter 2 by Ken Williamson

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out why I'm getting the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSES error below.  I am working on Chapter 2 of Learning AngularJS by Ken Williamson.  I typed in all the code exactly as it is in the book and set up the directory structure exactly as it is listed in the book.  However, when I try to run the project (locally on my computer), I get the following error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (22:27:47:397 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/AngularJsHelloWorld_chapter2/partials/main.html
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$compile/tpload?p0=partials%2Fmain.html&p1=-1&p2=
    at Error (native)

The code for the relevant pages look like this:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" ng-app="helloWorldApp"> 
    <head> 
        <title>AngularJS Hello World</title>             
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-   scale=1.0"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 

        <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/libs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script> 

        <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/services.js"></script> 


    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div ng-view></div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

main.html:

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

I realize I might need to provide additional information.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the directory structure:

https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920035831/learning-angularjs/14.xhtml?ref=toc#idp2844416

Here is the code on Github: https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920035831/learning-angularjs/14.xhtml?ref=toc#idp2844416

By the way, my directory is slightly different from the book in that I have the latest versions of the js framework in it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a known issue in ngRoute (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute):

> If ngView is contained in an asynchronously loaded template (e.g. in another directive's templateUrl or in a template loaded using ngInclude), then you need to make sure that $route is instantiated in time to capture the initial $locationChangeStart event and load the appropriate view. One way to achieve this is to have it as a dependency in a .run block: myModule.run(['$route', function() {}]);

Adding the following code should fix the error. It did for me when opening the web page locally.

```
helloWorldApp.run(['$route', function() {}]);
```